# Error using ImageMagick in Android - JMagick (java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load MagickLoader)

Tags: android, maven, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick (JMagick) in an Android application and for some reason I keep getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at com.example.testingjmagickthird.MyActivity.generateAnimation(MyActivity.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at com.example.testingjmagickthird.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:23)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10318): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load MagickLoader
```

Here's the actual code that triggers this:

```java
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/car.jpg";
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(path));
```

The path is correct, the same code works with a different ImageMagick library.

I'm using JMagick 6.6.9 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jmagick/jmagick), here's my POM file dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jmagick</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmagick</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.9</version> 
</dependency>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you solved the problem iam getting the same error in the line Enviornment.getExternalStorageDirectory().this is giving me ExceptionInInitializerError while i am doing testing for normally while i am launching the android app it works as usual.

Comment: I actually ended up not using JMagick, couldn't get it to work and ended up using a different library (found a Java implementation of the NeuQuant algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not explicitly need JMagick you could use another java binding for ImageMagick: [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/).

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.im4java</groupId>
  <artifactId>im4java</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```